# exported function is undefined in same file javascript

Tags: javascript

I am exporting function func().Also I need to call it locally i.e. in the same file.But calling it locally throws error stating that func is undefined.

```
export default async function func(dataType) {

}

navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', function handler (event) {
  func(); // **undefined**
})
```

Comment: have you tried to declare and export separately?

Comment: therres a difference between function declarations and function expressions...

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your code to

```
    export default async function func(dataType) {

}

navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', function handler (event) {
  this.func(); // **undefined**
})
```